# Obfuscate data during migration with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, migration, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to obfuscate sensible data during migration using MySQL Workbench?

We are going to work on site so we need to make a copy for develpment but the (MySQL) database contains sensible user data that need to be obfuscated for obvoius privacy reasons.

I already used MySQL WB migration wizard so it's not new to me, but i can't figure it out if it can obfuscate/alter data during migration apart from columns/tables definition.

Maybe it just can't, maybe there are better tools/ways to do what i need, but using a tool i already know and that can automagically create sql/ssh scripts would be better of course.

#### Precisation

with 'obfuscation' i mean any avalable way to alter data.
E.g.:

- transform user `first_name` property to something like `<user_id>_first_name`
- change any login password to a standard one
- replace fiscal code with a random string
- etc

Comment: It's a tricky task.  The distribution each column needs to be similar -- for optimizations, etc.

Comment: @RickJames can you explain?

Comment: The SSN in one table may need to match the SSN in another table.  It might be 'bad' to change "age" to be a random number between 0 and 100.  `has_high_blood_pressure`, if randomized might lead you about 50% of rows saying `yes`.

Comment: It's not a problem having such random data, we just need to have some data to test business logic, it's not (so) important to have unrealistic data at first, we just need to have a base to work with.

Comment: Would you be interested in a product that is given only a `CREATE TABLE`, and it creates som random days?  (I have heard of such, but don't know of any off hand.)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Better you do the migration first and then run a script over the copy to obfuscate fields.

Comment: do you mean that it's not possible because MySWL WB does not support this feature?

Comment: That is the case, yes.

Comment: thanks, are you aware of other tools for this purpose? something working on-the-fly would be very appreciated

Comment: Never heard of any, no.